# gtfs-editor compile time error

Tags: route, transit, general-transit-feed-specification

I'm trying to build the [gtfs_editor](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor) project by following the instructions on the given page.

But, while executing the command **play run** the log at `localhost:9000` says
`Compilation error
The file /app/controllers/Check.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Check is already defined`

Has anyone gone through this problem before?

I'm working on `play framework -1.2.5.3`,

Answer (score 1):

I have a fully functional, open source, freely hosted, GTFS editor called Gee here

https://github.com/mark-lester/Stretchsoft/tree/master/Gee

It is a fully functional GTFS editor that supports collaborative work on a freely hosted platform. The code is on github and is freely available.
I am trying to locate everyone currently involved in providing GTFS solutions in order to provide a front facing GTFS production facility for public use.

I tried, for several months, to get gtfs_editor to work and to locate the authors. I failed on both counts. It seems to be unable to upload arbitrary GTFS, only ones it created, It does not enable editing of the entire GTFS schema.

Comment: Late update: The code is available at https://github.com/mark-lester/Stretchsoft/tree/master/Gee. The linked homepage does not respond anymore.

Comment: Hi everyone, yeah chalo doesnt work. I have something on wikitmetable.com and code at https://github.com/mark-lester/Gemini I spent all of last yearon osne other futile project/ I am about to spend a few months playing on Indian trains but if there is anyone out there who believes in the need for something called wikitimetable please say hello